# Xamarin iOS - User-generated images disappear every time I run from Visual Studio

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I have an app, in which users take photos. I save these photos to the library and display them somewhere in the app. This all works great. However, every time I run the app from Visual Studio (excluding the session when the photos are taken), these images don't show up.

Launching the app from my device directly (so not in debugging mode) works as you would expect - I can see the images just fine.

I know there *must* be a way for this to work - the local database isn't wiped every time I run from Visual Studio for example - but I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

I've tried saving the images elsewhere (Resources, Application Data, root MyDocuments, etc), but to no avail.

Contents of `GetImagePath(string filename)` so you can see where I'm saving them:

```
string libPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "..", "Library");
return Path.Combine(libPath, filename);
```

Anybody here got any ideas? I think once the app is deployed it should be fine, but it's still damn annoying to have this happen whilst I'm developing.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here's my saving and loading code:
Saving: `NSData.FromArray(data).Save(path, true, out error)`

I'm displaying them like this:
`Content.Content = new Image { Source = filename }`

Comment: Can you put up your code that saving the images and also how you access the images?

Comment: @lowleetak I've edited the question for you, however, that information seems irrelevant to me? They are showing up the first time and all subsequent times until I involve Visual Studio. They don't disappear until I launch the app from VS.

Comment: for Android, there used to be a setting that would overwrite the app's local files each time you deployed.  I've never seen this happen on iOS.  And you're sure it's only happening selectively to images and not db files?  Have you tried using XCode to look at the app's file system?

Comment: @Jason - am 100% certain the DB files aren't being re-written. Which images to show is stored in the DB, this list creates the required elements correctly, the images are just all blank (all other data turns up ok though). I haven't yet tried using XCode to look through the app's file system as I didn't know that was a thing, but I'll give it a try :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a bit of playing around and stepping through code I've found the answer.

Your data in iOS is stored in an app container - the `GUID` associated with this container changes every time you build to the device. As I was storing the full file path instead of just the filename, the images weren't showing up after a re-deploy because the full file path was looking for a no-longer-extant app container. The contents of the `Library` and `Documents` folders are copied to the new app container each time - but using the full path from before the current version was build to the device wouldn't be able to find it.

Switching to only store the filename and getting the full file path each time I need to show an image fixed this issue.

I noticed this issue during development, but in production there would have been issues where images weren't being found after an app update.